# calling HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, async-await, httpclient

I have this code in C#

```
private async Task AAA(ClassInstance campanaRep)
{
  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("Http:...." + "WebMethod", campanaRep);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    bol = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
}
```

It Works fine....

I am trying to convert to VB.NET, that is what i could migrate

```
private sub AAA(campanaRep as ClassInstance )

  Using client As New HttpClient()
            client.BaseAddress = New Uri(apiUrl)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("Http:...." + "WebMethod", campanaRep);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    bol = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result
    end sub
End Function
```

I have an error on line

> HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("Http"+
>   "WebMethod", campanaRep)

I thing AAA Function has to be defined different. And assignation has to be different too, but I do not find the correct syntax.

How should it be?

Comment: You tell us you have an error but not what the error is...

Comment: Also from my limited memory of VB: You have no `End If`, there's a stray `End Function` at the end, you're missing an `End Using` and `bool` is `Boolean` (maybe)

Comment: What's the error?  Why is there a random `End Function` at the end of the VB code?  Don't you also need to `End` the `If` and the `Using`?  Doesn't VB use different syntax for supplying a type argument to a generic method?  Why are you invoking `.Result` instead of using `await` like you do elsewhere?  It's not really clear *which* problem in this code is the one you're currently trying to solve...

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you haven't marked your method as `Async` which makes the compiler tell you `Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors with your code, but it seems you are stuck on the compiler error suggesting that:

> Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses

This is because you haven't marked the method as `Async` so the compiler is assuming that `Await` is a function. So just add that to the signature:

```
Private Async Sub AAA(campanaRep As ClassInstance)
```

Also, the rest of the code is a complete mess, here it is tidied up somewhat:

```
Private Async Sub AAA(campanaRep As ClassInstance)
    Using client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
        client.BaseAddress = New Uri("")
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()

        Dim response As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = _
            Await client.PutAsJsonAsync("Http"+ "WebMethod", campanaRep)

        If (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            bol = Await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of Boolean)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```